# Can not apply string function on message fetched from imap_fetchbody function

Tags: php, email, imap

Getting message from imap_fetchbody function works absolutely fine & when I print the message, it's printing with no issues.
The problem is when I apply any substring function, it displays nothing. Ultimately it seems message is not regarded as a string.
Here is my code:

```
$email=imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "Mail delivery failed"', SE_UID);
foreach($email as $email_number) {

$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);    

$output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
$output.= '<span class="subject">subject'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
$output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
$output.= '<span class="to">'.$overview[0]->to.'</span>';
$output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
$output.= '</div>';    

$output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
}
function getBetween($message,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $message);
if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}
return '';
}
$start = "The following address(es) failed: ";
$end = " No Such User Here";
$newcontent = getBetween($message,$start,$end);
echo $newcontent;
```

Any idea how to convert $message into a string so that I can apply the functions? And yes, basically I want to have specific part between two strings from email.

**EDIT**

If someone is suspected about getting the output, then the result for`echo $message` is below:

```
**This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients.
This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed: xxx@example.com
No Such User Here"...**
```

Comment: Why are you using `explode` to get a substring? Wouldn't be `$temp =  substr($message, 0, strpos($message, $end)); return substr($temp, strpos($temp, $start));` be suffice?

Comment: To my shock, it's working but not fully. It gives me whole string until start of $end. So like "This message...example.com"

Comment: Try this: `$temp = substr($message, strpos($temp, $start)); return substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, $end));`. Also, remove the space before `No Such User Here`

Comment: I used a little different thing, & that worked. You can post this as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getBetween` function does not do what it should do.

```
function getBetween($message, $start, $end){
    $temp = substr($message, strpos($message, $start) + strlen($start)); // Get the first part, excluding the start text
    return substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, $end)); // Remove the last part
}
```